# How to convert proxy object to json in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Having little project in fast api / vue. Currently I need to pass some values and store them in vuex. I have the logic which works correctly, however I'm struggling with reading the passed object (from component to store action's method). Probably I could do it via JSON.parse(), but I'm not sure if it is the correct way. How can I access this object's keys?

store:

```
  mutations: {
    add_pizza_to_order(state: State, OrderedPizza: OrderedPizza){
      console.log(OrderedPizza)
      // contains keys like pizza, amount etc. Accessing OrderedPizza.pizza returns undefined
    }
  },
  actions: {
    make_order(context, OrderedPizza: OrderedPizza){
      context.commit('add_pizza_to_order', OrderedPizza)
    }
  },
```

component:

```
setup(props){
        const STORE = useStore(key)
        const _pizza_size = ["small", "medium", "big"]

        const amount = ref(1)
        const size_choice = ref('medium')

        const func_make_order = ()=>{
          STORE.dispatch('make_order',{
            OrderedPizza: {
              pizza: props.pizza,
              amount: amount,
              size: size_choice
            }
          })
        }

        return{
          _pizza_size, size_choice, amount, STORE, props, func_make_order
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the keys, you can use `Object.keys(proxy)` on the proxy.

Converting a proxy to object is done easiest with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(proxy))`

Note also that your action and dispatch are not matching

```js
STORE.dispatch('make_order',{
  OrderedPizza: {
    pizza: props.pizza,
    amount: amount,
    size: size_choice
  }
})
```

will pass an object with `OrderedPizza` as an item in the object

your action and mutation expect the object passed to be the `OrderedPizza`, so the reason you're not seeing it is that you would technically need `console.log(OrderedPizza.OrderedPizza.pizza)`

you can fix that either by removing the nested object:

```js
STORE.dispatch('make_order',{
  pizza: props.pizza,
  amount: amount,
  size: size_choice
})
```

**or** getting it in the action by destructuring the passed parameter (note the `{}` around `OrderedPizza: OrderedPizza`)

```js
actions: {
  make_order(context, {OrderedPizza: OrderedPizza}){
    context.commit('add_pizza_to_order', OrderedPizza)
  }
},
```